# HTML Multiple classes on button element

Tags: html, css, class

I understand that elements can have multiple classes:

```
.rfrsh-btn {
    background-image:url(../../upload/rfrsh_nb_grey.png);
    ... 
}

.submit
{
    font-size: 0.85em;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This was working perfectly as an ID before. now I changed it to a class and lo and behold, no images.

But for some reason this `<button>` element doesn't seem to want to display with a background image and styles applied.

Is there a reason for this? Or am I codeblind and doing something wrong.

I can't use ID either as it's repeated many times on the page.

Thanks all :)

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the HTML and CSS you posted. What are you trying to do, and what's happening instead?

Comment: This `<button>` element doesn't seem to want to do what exactly?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but most major browser have developer tools or plugins that allow you to select a page element and determine which styles are or are not applied. Firebug for Firefox, or Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar are examples of tools that might help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: Yeah, using Firebug and Chrome's developer tools. Also, edited question to clarify.

Comment: Just replaced underscores with hyphens. No change, will try separate classnames then no hyphens.

Comment: Miraculously it worked when I removed one classname, then stillworked when I added the other one back in... Well it works now, thanks very much.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons. For instance, it's quite possible your image path is not correct. It 's worth noting that paths in CSS are relative to the .css file 's location, and not to the including page.

To better understand what's going on now and in the future, however, I recommend either working with Chrome, which offers a nice set of debugging tools, or use Firefox with Firebug installed. This way you can inspect your elements and see what styles get applied, overlapped, or any images the browser cannot locate.

For more information: http://www.thetruetribe.com/2008/03/firebug-tutorial-getting-started/

Comment: +1 for Firebug, I've been using it and all image paths are present and correct. This was working perfectly as an ID before. now I cahnged it to a class and lo and behold, no images.

Comment: Does the CSS tab reveal any overlapping styles in the button, which would prevent the style from working? Or, perhaps the old CSS gets cached?

Answer (score 0):

Underscores in class names can cause issues. Try renaming rfrsh_btn.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Underscores_in_class_and_ID_Names

Comment: Oh come *on*! All of the browsers on that list are at least 10 years old! This is hardly relevant information.

Comment: Interesting, but that was written in 2006 and I don't think this is still an issue (and even that article says IE6 handles them fine):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686337/hyphens-or-underscores-in-css-and-html-identifiers